# How can dragonfiresdk be so sure to be appstore compliant?

Tags: iphone

How dragonfiresdk works internally as It allows to develop on Windows ? As Apple rules seem harsh about porting code how can dragonforesdk be so sure to be compliant ? Why aren't there any other solutions for developping iphone on Windows then or are there ?

Seems like a mystery to everybody ...

Update: as Brad Larson asked, I'm curious to know the answer too:

If the application is compiled on a Mac, how does this help you develop using only Windows? A Mac is still required for compilation / codesigning ?

Answer (score 0):

Appstore has several Dragonfiresdk powered apps from Zimusoft currently. Also check their forums. There seems to be several people with their apps up in the app store.

Since the final app after compilation is a true native app, I don't think Dragonfiresdk has anything problematic that Apple will ban it.